# Pandas multiply DataFrames with element-wise match of index and column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multiplication, elementwise-operations

I have two pandas DataFrames, with one of them having index and columns that are subsets of the other. For example:

`DF1 =`

```
date        a     b    c
20170101    1.0   2.2  3
20170102    2.1   5.2  -3.0
20170103    4.2   1.8  10.0
...
20170331    9.8   5.1  4.5
```

`DF2 =`

```
date        a     c
20170101    NaN   2.1
20170103    4     NaN
```

What I want is element-wise multiplication by matching both the index and column. i.e. only `DF1[20170103]['c']` will be multiplied with `DF2[20170103]['c']`, etc.

The resulting DF should have the same dimension as the bigger one (`DF1`), with missing values in `DF2` set as the original `DF1` value:

`result DF =`

```
date        a     b    c
20170101    1.0   2.2  6.3
20170102    2.1   5.2  -3.0
20170103    16.8  1.8  10.0
...
20170331    9.8   5.1  4.5
```

What's the best/fastest way to do this? The real-life matrices are huge, and DF2 is relatively sparse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need vectorized function [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
df = DF1.mul(DF2, fill_value=1)
print (df)
             a    b     c
date                     
20170101   1.0  2.2   6.3
20170102   2.1  5.2  -3.0
20170103  16.8  1.8  10.0
20170331   9.8  5.1   4.5
```

Comment: Has Pandas updated to no longer work with .mul?? I have been trying to do something like this but I am continuously getting errors in the execution.